# used dd-wrt to turn my router into an access point for better signal in my new apartment. It stopped giving me an internet signal after a few days

Tags: networking, wireless-access-point, dd-wrt

I wanted an access point at my new apartment which has community internet so I put the dd-wrt firmware on my router and everything works for 5 days then no more access point.  I can't connect to it unless I directly use the Ethernet cable, yet I still don't get any internet.

I was thinking that the 'network / it' people they have working here saw that I setup an ap and blocked all contact with it (with its mac address?)

I talked to a fellow at best buy, not overly helpful, but he mentioned cloning the mac.  I guess this would prevent the network admins from telling whether or not the device is a computer or an access point.

Could someone please explain this whole concept of mac cloning for this purpose and give me insight into what needs to be cloned.  I have been wondering if I need to use one of my computers mac addresses and clone it to the ap...  I don't know

All help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Please delete this question and ask on [su]; home networking questions are off-topic for [so]

Comment: How are you 'getting better signal'? Are you repeating the signal wirelessly? Or are you plugged in and broadcasting your own access point?

Comment: @MikePennington I was just about to then noticed the logo at the top had changed to superuser.  Thank you who ever migrated my question.

Comment: @r.tanner.f I have an excellent signal in my living room with my desktop and the 'dd-wrt' router.  However in my bedroom I can hardly get a signal on the apartment wi-fi so my router in the living room provides a much stronger signal.

Comment: @AdamJohnston What's your configuration like in DD-WRT? Wireless repeater? Wired Repeater? I'd be a little surprised if you're getting blocked by MAC, but it might not hurt to try cloning your PC's MAC address. If you cant find the setting I'll throw together some screen shots later.